# Is there a way to push RecyclerView up with soft keyboard? (Chat)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to keep the current item of my chat recycler view visible when the user types something and the soft keyboard appears. Currently, it's overlaying the chat, I need the recycler view items to go up with the keyboard.

I tried these in my manifest :

```
-android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
-android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

And I changed the XML Layout of my chat for testing each windowSoftInputMode :

-One Linear Layout for the bottom edit text and send button + One Linear layout for the recycler view, both wrapped in one root linear layout, use the weight attribute set at 1 for the recycler view Linear Layout and 0 for the bottom linear layout.

-Two child Linear Layout wrapped in a root Relative Layout

-Two child Constraint Layout wrapped in a root Constraint Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".GroupChatFragment">

    <!-- RECYCLERVIEW CONTAINER -->


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_recycler_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/chat_add_message_container"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chat_add_message_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/chat_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 <!-- BOTTOM CONTAINER -->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_add_message_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <!-- TEXT MESSAGE EDIT TEXT -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/message_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:hint="Exprimez-vous..."
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/chat_send_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- ADD MESSAGE BUTTON -->
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_paper_plane"
            android:tint="@color/blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I still can't figure out how to achieve this. 
It's a basic feature that all chat apps are using.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE );

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't push the recycler view items up view up with the keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

**Set windowSoftInputMode in Manifest-activity adjustResize**

```
 <activity
        ..
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```